# Can edit_order_path be wired to the "modify" action (not the "edit" action) of the Orders controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_order_path(@order) %>
```

Is it possible to wire this link to the **modify action** of the Orders controller (instead of the **edit action**) **without changing this syntax**:

```
edit_order_path(@order)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

routes.rb:

```
map.edit_order "order/modify/:id" ,
:controller => "order" ,
:action => "modify" ,
:id => /\d+/
```